# How to multiple two input fields values and display it in third field as output using visualforce/apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have written vf and apex as below code mentioned and i am unable to gt the output:-
[image]

### vf

```
<script>
function checkAllOrNone(allOrNoneCheckbox) {
    var container = allOrNoneCheckbox;
    while (container.tagName != "TABLE") {
        container = container.parentNode;
    }
    var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var checked = allOrNoneCheckbox.checked;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
        var input = inputs.item(i);
        if (input.type == "checkbox") {
            if (input != allOrNoneCheckbox) {
                input.checked = checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchprts}" reRender="product-table" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="product-table" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Products}" var="c">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox id="chkbox" onclick="checkAllOrNone(this)"/>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                    {!c.Name}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header" >amt</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText id="id1" value="{!c.amt__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Qnty</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputField id="id2" value="{!c.q__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Total </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText id="id3" value="{!ttl }"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

apex

```
public with sharing class Ctrl_ContactSearch
{
    public List<Product2> Products { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public decimal total = 0;

    public Ctrl_ContactSearch()
    {
        total = 0;
        Products = new List<Product2>();
    }

    public PageReference searchprts()
    {
        Products = [select Id,Name,amt__c,q__c from Product2 where Name = :name];

    }
    public void ttl() {
       ttl = amt__c*q__c ;
    }
}
```

Also i would like to store the output in other fields of custom object.

Answer (score 3):

Visualforce can't find the property `ttl` because you do not have a getter method available. You would need to change

```
public void ttl()
```

to

```
public void getttl()
```

or store the value in an instance variable with synthesized getters and setters (you already have one called `total` that you aren't using):

```
public Decimal ttl { get; set; }
```

Comment: Haha `getttl()` totally looks like a typo. Probably a marginal improvement to use `getTtl()`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the variable-naming-and-nomenclature rabbit hole. Can't believe we don't have a decent Apex linter yet.

Comment: I just meant three lower case ts in a row. Property syntax definitely superior here.

Comment: i tried with below changes but still i am not getting the result as multiple of two fields values containing one input and output text:- <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Total </apex:facet>
                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!total}" event="onblur" reRender="frm"/>
                        <apex:outputText id="id3" value="{!ttl}"/>
                    </apex:column>

Comment: Comments are not for iterative debugging. You're welcome to ask a new question if you need assistance with a different issue.